# How to return byte[] as multipartFile as response to UI?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, multipartform-data

The attachment is already stored in the database. The Api which I was trying to achieve is getting the attachment Id as input and sending the respective byte[] as multipartFile as response to UI.

The current code snippet is:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST }, value = "/getData", produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> getAttachmentDetails(@RequestBody Integer attachmentId) {
   MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
   byte[] result = emailIntakeService.getAttachmentDetails(attachmentId);
   formData.add("file", result);    
   return new ResponseEntity<>(formData,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the response : file=%5BB%4011a93325

Can someone help how to send byte[] as multipartFile as reponse.

Comment: You don't say how you want it to look, but have you tried wrapping the `result` in a [`ByteArrayResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ByteArrayResource.html) when adding it to the `formData` `Map`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST }, value = "/getData")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAttachmentDetails(@RequestBody Integer attachmentId) {
   MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
   byte[] result = emailIntakeService.getAttachmentDetails(attachmentId);
   return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + "filename.xls" + "\"")
        .body(result);
}
```